# Error during upgrade : Oracle 11g to 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-11g, upgrade, suse-linux

While upgrading `catupgrade.sql`, we are getting below error.

> Due to errors found during the upgrade process, the post
>   upgrade actions in catuppst.sql have not been automatically run.
>
> *** THEREFORE THE DATABASE UPGRADE IS NOT YET COMPLETE ***
>
> 1. Evaluate the errors found in the upgrade logs
>      and determine the proper action.
>
>    2. Execute the post upgrade script as described in Chapter 3
>         of the Database Upgrade Guide.
>
> REASON:
>   catuppst.sql unable to run in Database: EluxTest Id: 0
>
> ### ERRORS FOUND: during upgrade CATCTL ERROR COUNT=6
>
> Identifier CATALOG 20-01-27 02:20:04 Script = c1102000.sql
>   ERROR = [ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P000 ORA-01115: IO error reading block from file  (block # )
>
> ORA-01115: IO error reading block from file 2 (block # 215616)
>
> ORA-27072: File I/O error
>
> Additional information: 4
>
> Additional information: 215616
>
> Additional information: 212992
>
> ORA-06512: at line 8
>   ]
>   STATEMENT = [BEGIN
>    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
>     'create unique index WRH$_EVENT_HISTOGRAM_PK on WRH$_EVENT_HISTOGRAM
>       (dbid, snap_id, instance_number, event_id, wait_time_milli, con_dbid)
>      local nologging parallel
>      tablespace sysaux';
>   EXCEPTION
>    WHEN OTHERS THEN IF (SQLCODE = -942) THEN NULL; ELSE RAISE; END IF;
>   END;]

Tried various solutions mentioned below posted online in various forums, but nothing worked.

- Increased SGA to 6GB
- Altered Data file `sysaux01` to AUTOEXTEND OFF
- Altered datafile to `ONLINE`

Answer (score 2):

The real error is:

```
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P000 ORA-01115: IO error reading block from file (block # )
ORA-01115: IO error reading block from file 2 (block # 215616)
ORA-27072: File I/O error
Additional information: 4
Additional information: 215616
Additional information: 212992
```

The "solutions" you tried make no sense when you get something like this.

Fix the storage/filesystem first.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please let me know What exactly should I fix in Storage/filesystem? Everything seems to be fine.

Comment: @Omega File 2 (usually SYSAUX datafile) could not be read at block 215616 due to an error in an underlying layer. Try to copy/read this file with standard OS commands to see if it can be read at all. You may get an error there, if so, then I would umount the filesystem, try to check and repair with fsck. At this point, the datafile may become corrupt (from database perspective), so be prepared to recover it from backup, which you always should be anyways.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I will check this and update you.